# Eclipse plugin development editor font

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, xtext, pde

I am using Eclipse 3.7.0 for plugin development and I am using Xtext 2.9.2. My editor preferences isn't working correctly.

On windows **7, 8, 10** this happens:

[image].

- On 64 bit builds, I am not able to change editor font. Hitting the change button does nothing but change the mouse to the busy/sandclock for a second and then back again to normal.

  - **The same 64 bit builds were tested on windows XP and everything works as it should.**
- On 32 bit builds, everything works as expected and the windows font picker dialog appears.

[image]

This is how I create the preference page:

```
@Override
protected void createFieldEditors() {
  // Add show font preference
  fontField = new FontFieldEditor(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT, EDIT_EDITOR_FONT_LABEL, getFieldEditorParent());
  addField(fontField);

  fontField.setPreferenceStore(getPreferenceStore());

  // initialize the font preference with the default resources font if not initialized
  String defaultFont = getPreferenceStore().getDefaultString(JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT);
  if(defaultFont.isEmpty()) {
     font= JFaceResources.getTextFont();
     if (font != null) {
        FontData[] data= font.getFontData();
        if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
           PreferenceConverter.setDefault(getPreferenceStore(), JFaceResources.TEXT_FONT, data[0]);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

---

The `.log` file is empty and has nothing that is beneficial.

---

While debugging, I went to `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FontDialog.java` and found that this line always returns false without the dialog appearing. From what I understand this call should be blocking and will only return when the dialog is closed either by X, OK or Cancel buttons but it returns immediately with false.

```
/* Open the dialog */
boolean success = OS.ChooseFont (lpcf)
```

---

I also tried something as minimal as this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FontDialogExample.htm) and same thing happens.

Comment: Anything in the .log file. Eclipse 3.7 is very old.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, unfortunately it's super old but I have to use it. This issue doesn't cause any crashes for a .log file to be written. I can't locate any .log files. Mouse only changes to sandclock/busy pointer for 1 second and then back to normal when I press Change and nothing happens.

Comment: The `.log` file is in the workspace `.metadata` directory - both the file and directory are hidden on macOS or Linux. There doesn't have to be a crash to get things written to the log.

Comment: Well yeah I have found it. However nothing gets written down when I click change.

Comment: @greg-449 Please check my edits.

Comment: Not much I can say since I use Eclipse 4.6/4.7 on macOS. If it works on Windows XP but not Windows 7 then it may be a bug - but you won't get any bug fixes for Eclipse 3.7 which went out of support long ago. I don't see anything obvious searching on [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/query.cgi?format=advanced)

Comment: @greg-449 Okay thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Months passed and I figured out what was causing the issue.

Basically we have a `JNI` layer which loads some `dll` that requires `MSVCR90.dll`. This requires embedding `MSVCR90.dll` manifest into `eclipse.exe` used for our `RCP`, this is done using `mt.exe` provided by `Microsoft Visual Studio`.

While building I accidentally didn't embed the `MSVCR90.dll` manifest, this resulted into the error during loading the `dll` which says that `MSVCR90.dll` is missing. I however noticed that the treeview styling looked correct.

This was also the answer to my other question [Eclipse RCP Jface/SWT TreeViewer on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955759/eclipse-rcp-jface-swt-treeviewer-on-windows-10/). The manifest also affected the `UI` look and feel `treeviews` and `progressbars` didn't look like the ones provided by the `OS`.