# Eclipse RCP Jface/SWT TreeViewer on Windows 10

Tags: eclipse, treeview, windows-10, swt, jface

I have a RCP application. I recently moved the application to 64 bit. It is based on Eclipse 3.7.0.

I noticed something weird. There is a discrepancy between TreeViewer expand/collapse icons on 32 and 64 bit builds on Windows 10.

From what I understand it goes down to the OS which determines the theme and what to use for the icon.

On 32 bit builds TreeViewer expand/collapse looks like:

[image: 32 bit TreeViewer expand/collapse Windows 10]

On 64 bit builds TreeViewer expand/collapse looks like:

[image: 64 bit TreeViewer expand/collapse Windows 10]

Why are 64 bit builds only using + -? This only happens within my tool. The 64 bit Eclipse platform I am using shows the correct expand/collapse Windows 10 icons.

What can I possibly be doing wrong? Where should I start looking?

I have checked all my initializations of TreeViewers and I am not giving anything special style-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Months passed and I figured out what was causing the issue.

Basically we have a `JNI` layer which loads some `dll` that requires `MSVCR90.dll`. This requires embedding `MSVCR90.dll` manifest into `eclipse.exe` used for our `RCP`, this is done using `mt.exe` provided by `Microsoft Visual Studio`.

While building I accidentally didn't embed the `MSVCR90.dll` manifest, this resulted into the error during loading the `dll` which says that `MSVCR90.dll` is missing. I however noticed that the treeview styling looked correct.